# how can i do the Gesture Recognizer with cocos2d for iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

how can i do the Gesture Recognizer with cocos2d for iphone?
only left/right/up/down
can any body give me some example or tutorial?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[guestures](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) below code is some example for swipeguesture you can get hole documentation from the above link.in the didswipe method is user method

```
`UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRecognizerright = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    swipeGestureRecognizerright.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    swipeGestureRecognizerright.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeGestureRecognizerright.delegate = self;

    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRecognizerright];
    [swipeGestureRecognizerright release];

-(void)didswipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
//do something


}
`
```